# Python not allowing me to remove object from list as a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on creating texas holdem in Python, and I have ran into my first problem. I gave the player a random hand from the deck, and now, i want to remove the cards inside the hand to prevent duplicates. Since the hand is random, I need to remove the cards from the list as a variable. Here is what I have.
deck is the name of the list (I listed out every card in a regular deck)

```
hand = random.sample((deck),2)
print('your hand is', hand)
deck.remove(hand)
```

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicates, why not use a `set`?

Comment: Also, `remove` works in-place, don't expect to have it return you anything.

Comment: What exactly is the problem. What's not working? Are you getting an error? Can you create a [mcve] of your problem. What is your expected output? What is your actually output?

Comment: `remove` removes *one* element, not a list of elements.

Comment: I think what he's referring to is the problem of dealing the same cards to two different players.  To prevent that, you must remove each card from the deck as it is "dealt".  Probably "duplicates" was a poor choice of word.

Comment: sorry, today is my second day of python, so I am not too familiar with syntax and language.

Comment: Paul Cornelius is correct, I am trying to make sure that the same card doesnt show up twice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a set to represent hands, as @COLDSPEED mentioned, or if you are representing the deck as a list, and assuming all cards in the deck are unique, pop them off as you generate a hand.

E.G.

```
deck = ['JS','QS','KS','AS' ....]
```

draw one card:

```
card = deck.pop()
```

**EDIT**

Here is more complete example, including randomness

```
import random

deck = ['JS','QS','KS','AS']

def draw(num_cards,deck):
    hand = []
    for n in range(num_cards):
        card = random.choice(deck)
        hand.append(card)
        deck.remove(card)
    return hand

print(draw(2,deck))
print(deck)
```

And a version using sets, as requested:

```
import random

class Poker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck =  {'JS','QS','KS','AS'}

    def draw(self,num_cards):
        hand = set(random.sample(self.deck,num_cards))
        self.deck = self.deck.difference(hand)
        return hand

game = Poker()
hand = game.draw(2)
print(hand)
print(game.deck)
```

Comment: Where is the randomness?

Comment: As I am rather new to this, how do I use a set in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find a list object inside of another list object.  What you actually need to do here is use a loop, so instead of `deck.remove(hand)`, you should do:

```
for x in hand:
  deck.remove(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are taking a random sample with parameter `2`, you will get a list of two elements. Therefore, it is best to filter the list like so:

```
hand = random.sample((deck),2)
print('your hand is', hand)
deck = [i for i in deck if i not in hand]
```

Answer (score 0):

`deck.remove` expects a single item that exists within `deck`. You can't pass it a list of items hoping it will remove each individual item in the list. It will instead try to find the passed list inside `deck`.

You need to do either:

```
for x in hand:
    deck.remove(x)
```

or:

```
deck.remove(hand[0])
deck.remove(hand[1])
```

Better still, make this more like how we usually think of a pack of cards.

```
random.shuffle(deck)
hand = [deck.pop(), deck.pop()]
```